# How to extract query placeholders for debug purposes?

Tags: database, debugging

When I cast query to string, I can see `WHERE` that will be passed to the database, like this:

```
WHERE  (idProperty = :db_condition_placeholder_0)
  AND  (idCategory = :db_condition_placeholder_1)
```

But how can I extract these placeholders?

Comment: Wasn't able to find it here. Not that complicated, but I believe it may be useful for some readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [`arguments`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Aarguments/7):

```
echo (string)$query;
var_dump($query->arguments());
```

This simple code will give you both query and arguments, for simple debugging.