# Drupal 7 special chars not working in db_select

Tags: database

I have implemented custom search to get some values from node.

When I'm using special chars like "**/, ?, !**", no result is being displayed.

Example value : "**24/7**" or "**site?**" or "**test!**", etc...

```
$search_text = '24/7';
$query->condition(db_or()
->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like($search_text) . '%', 'LIKE')
->condition('fld.body_value', '%' . db_like($search_text) . '%', 'LIKE'));
```

I'm running my site in Drupal 7. **PHP version is 5.5.9. Using Mysql DB.** OS windows.

Note:
Query is correct. Its giving proper result for other than special chars.

**Edit:**
$query->arguments(); is returning below image. [image]

I was running LIKE command in phpmyadmin. Please find that screen shot below.

[image]

So what is the modification do we need to do at PDO to support this issue?

Comment: And what `db_like($search_text)` actually returns? See [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/128086/16495) - that's how you can extract both rendered query, and placeholders. Do it, edit it into your question, and we might be able to help.

Comment: I just checked - `db_like` is nothing more than sophisticated wrapper around [`addcslashes`](http://pl1.php.net/addcslashes) with simple parameters: `addcslashes($string, '\%_')`. It shouldn't affect your strings in any way, if it does, we will also need your PHP version and database driver you use with your Drupal. and the data I already requested, of course.

Comment: Those chars aren't special, they're just as ascii as every other char you're using `db_like('24/7')` returns the string `24/7` (as you'd expect), so your problem is somewhere else. Cast the `$query` object to a string and see what the SQL is like. That should show you where the problem is

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like anything wrong with query. I'm using drupal 7 with basic setup and one node(nid=3) has 24/7 in title & body and one node(nid=4) has only in body.

```
  // Make sure to decode, if the search string is part of URL.
  // $search_text = urldecode($_GET['query']);

  $search_text = '24/7';
  $query = db_select('node', 'n');
  $query->join('field_data_body', 'b', 'b.entity_id=n.nid');
  $query->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->condition(db_or()
    ->condition('n.title', '%' . db_like($search_text) . '%', 'LIKE')
    ->condition('b.body_value', '%' . db_like($search_text) . '%', 'LIKE')
  );
  $result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
  print_r(db_like($search_text));
  print_r($query->arguments());
  print_r($result);
```

and the result is:

```
// print_r(db_like($search_text));
24/7

// print_r($query->arguments());
Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => %24/7%
    [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => %24/7%
)

// print_r($result);
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [nid] => 3
        )

)
```

**Note**: If you are getting the search string from URL as query string make sure, you have done `urldecode()` before send to SQL.

Comment: Thanks vijay for your answer. I'm getting this value from url. Ex: url?text=24/7. Here how can I sanitize my input (Text)? If we do sanitization, it should work with db_like.

Comment: Updated the note with URL specific details.

Comment: hey @vijaycs85, good to see you on Drupal Answers!

Comment: @vijay: `dsm(urldecode("24/7 <script> alert('hi') </script>"));` It should not sanitize input.